# Execution of Console.writeline in below code

Tags: c#

```
namespace VariableDefinition
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            short a;
            int b ;
            double c;

            /* actual initialization */
            a = 10;
            b = 20;
            c = a + b;
            Console.WriteLine("a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}", a, b, c);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly explain me the meaning of a={0} b={1} and c={2} in console.writeline statement.
what does 0,1,2 stand for

Comment: I would run this after PaulG's response and see what happens. Then I would recommend changing it up a little. Do:
`"a = {1}, b = {0}, c = {2}"` 
and see what happens

Comment: I don't see how this is specific to C# 4.0. The C# tag is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Also, read documentation for [Console.Writeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.80).aspx) - .Net 2.0+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are placeholders for variables. The 3 placeholders in the string correspond to the 3 variable arguments which appear after the string.

The variable in the first placeholder is populated by the first argument (`a` in this case).
Second placeholder by the second argument (`b`) and the third by the third argument (`c`).

The code you posted should print the following to console:

`a = 10, b = 20, c = 30`